# How do you query a list from a table and include its total matches from a sub table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a list of cities.

I have another table with a table of listings.

How do I query the list of cities and include a column with the total number of listings for that city?

I have:

```
SELECT a.*,(SELECT COUNT FROM tbl_listings WHERE city=a.id) AS cnt FROM tbl_cities
```

Database Structure(ish)

CITIES

```
ID | CITY

01 | Atlanta

02 | Boston
```

LISTINGS (one example)

```
ID | CTY| DETAILS

01 | 01 | Listing 1

02 | 01 | Listing 2


DESIRED RESULT

01 | Atlanta | 345

02 | Boston  | 43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl_listings WHERE city=a.id) AS cnt 
FROM tbl_cities a
```

btw, avoid using `a.*` in sql statement. It make the process slower.

You might try this one:

```
select a.id,a.city,list.cnt
from cities a
left join (
    select city,count(*) as cnt 
    from listings
    group by city
) as list on list.city = a.id
```

Comment: how relevant is using a.* in terms of acceptable performance? when i use a.* the query takes .2 seconds (millions of records) since the table has over 100 columns this seems acceptable to me to avoid pages of queries to get all the columns. granted, i did not take the time to write a query to include all the columns but i am sure it would be much faster. the question is does it matter? especially since subsequent queries of the same are cashed and take .0000004 sec